# Shapes disappear when selecting keyframe

Tags: keyframes, 2d

Absolute beginner here. I am trying make a simple 2D animation, and have run into a strange problem. I have drawn the shapes, and inserted the starting keyframe. Then, on the timeline, I move the time marker to another frame (100), and on the screen move the shapes to the place I want to have them at frame 100.
I go to the timeline and insert a keyframe. Everything looks fine.

Then I select the keyframe that was just created, and all shapes disappear. I have not seen this happen in any of the tutorials that I have watched / read. If I play the animation then it looks great until frame 99, and then the shapes disappear and don't come back. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in Blender?

This Blender 2.82a on MacOs 10.15.4 Catalina, if it makes a difference.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot from just before adding the keyframe:

[image]

And one from just after selecting the new keyframe:

[image]

A movie of the whole sequence can be found here:

http://renevision.com/ScreenRecording3.mov

Comment: can you post images

Comment: @JacksonPro I have added screenshots now. Would be great if you could help!